# Python Error When Attempting to Iterate Over a List of File Names

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a list of file names, all of which have the .csv ending. I am trying to use the linecache.getline function to get 2 parts of each csv - the second row, 5th item and the 46th row, 5th item and comparing the two values (they're stock returns).

```
import csv
import linecache

d = open('successful_scrapes.csv')
csv = csv.reader(d)

k = []

for row in csv:
    k.append(row)

x =linecache.getline('^N225.csv',2)
y = float(x.split(",")[4])

for c in k:
    g = linecache.getline(c,2)
    t = float(g.split(",")[4])
```

Everything works until the for loop over the k list. It keeps returning the error "Unhashable type: list." I've tried including quotation marks before and after each .csv file name in the list. Additionally, all the files are included in the same directory. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have headers in the csvs?

Comment: Yes. The headers are on row 1. There are no headers in the list of csvs.

Comment: Why are you using both CSV and linecache?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and then just append the values to a list depending on the row number.

```
import csv
with open("C/a.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lst = [x[4] for i, x in enumerate(reader) if i == 1 or i == 45]
```

Then you can do the comparison with the `lst`'s items

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `linecache`, which is for working with files. There is no point in using it at all if you are going to pull the whole file into memory first.

In this case, since you have the whole CSV copied into `k`, just do the comparison:

`yourComparisonFunction(k[1][4],k[45][4])`

Alternately, you could use `linecache` instead of `csv`, and do it like so:

```
import linecache

file_list = ['file1','file2','file3','etc']

for f in file_list:

    line2 = linecache.getline(f,2)
    line2val = float(line2.split(",")[4])
    line46 = linecache.getline(f,46)
    line46val = float(line46.split(",")[4])
```

And the, I assume, add some comparison logic.